# Message "You should never see this warning." in Extbase-based Typo3 extension

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have an Extbase-based extension for Typo3, which has a hierarchical data model. I had to insert an additional layer to this model, ie the original structure was `Project contains multiple items`. Now, I have `Project contains multiple sub-projects` and `Sub-project contains multiple items`. Everything is modelled using MM-relation tables and works in the backend. I can add, remove, sort the sub-projects and items.

However, the fluid template does not show anything and if I pass eg the sub-Project to `t3lib_utilities_debug::Debug`, I get

> You should never see this warning. If you do, you probably used PHP
>   array functions like current() on the
>   Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage. To retrieve the first result,
>   you can use the rewind() and current() methods.

when printing the `ObjectStorage` for the items. I assume that the MM-relation I added is somehow broken, but I cannot figure out how. Furthermore, it seems that the `__construct` method of the domain model is not called (I have added a debug output, which is not printed).

The enumeration works if I pass the result of a call to `findAll` of the repository, but it does not work for my filtered calls (which worked before I added the additional layer). The filtering method looks like eg for the item

```
public function findBySubProject(SubProject $p) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $query->matching($query->equals('subproject', $p));
    return $query->execute();
}
```

As I said, the query yields results, but they are somehow broken wrt. their relations.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I case someone else encounters the same issue: I accidentally used an object without items as test object. If you try to enumerate/debug/display an empty `ObjectStorage`, the warning is printed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know on which version of Extbase you're developing on.

But on `TYPO3 4.6+` you should be aware of the `object` and `reflection` caching. During development you can disable this `caching` by:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['extbase_reflection']['backend'] = 't3lib_cache_backend_NullBackend';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['extbase_object']['backend'] = 't3lib_cache_backend_NullBackend';
```

Since your problem has something to do with modifications in your model you should try to truncate the tables `cf_extbase_object`, `cf_extbase_object_tags`, `cf_extbase_reflection` and `cf_extbase_reflection_tags` after any change.

If this doesn't help you to resolve your problem then you should give us more insight about your configuration (especially the TCA configuration because Extbase rely on it).

**How to test a Extbase QueryResult**

```
$items = $this->itemRepository->findAll();

echo count($items);

if ($items) {

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print_r($item);     
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

-- edit --

Did you define the field `subproject` in your TCA? It should be atleast available as type `passtrough`:

```
    'subproject' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'passthrough',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: That is an interesting information - thank you for that. However, I just had an emtpy query result which causes the error message in debug view. Btw. I am on 4.7.

Comment: Did you define the field 'subproject' in your TCA configuration? If not you should set it as `passthrough (I edited my answer).